# Translation of the word to the next line in the mysql console

Tags: mysql, database

```
mysql>SELECT LENGTH("boo
m"); //5  (I want 4)
```

How should I translate words on the next line without increasing the value of the number of characters?

Comment: You don't. Linefeed is always at least one character, two if on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
mysql> SELECT LENGTH("boo"
    -> "m");
+-------------------+
| LENGTH("boo"
"m") |
+-------------------+
|                 4 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To understand this see this example:

```
mysql> SELECT "boo" "m";
+------+
| boo  |
+------+
| boom |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can see same behavior in many programming languages.

Comment: @zloctb now you might like to read MySQL's doc [9.1.1 String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html)